# Selenium with Python does not print console.log messages

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, logging, selenium-chromedriver

My problem is, I can not see any of ***console.log, console.error, console.warning*** messages in my logs when I run this Python script:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class ChromeDriver():

    def __init__(login_url, user, passwd):
        self.login_url = login_url
        self.user = user
        self.passwd = passwd

    def __enter__(self):
        options = Options()
        options.set_capability('goog:loggingPrefs', {'browser': 'ALL'})
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self._login()
        return self.driver

    def _login():
        pass # implement login

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.driver.quit()

def check_console_logs(driver, url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'title'))
        )
        if '404' in driver.title:
            print(f'failed to open {url}: 404 Not found')
            return

        logs = driver.get_log('browser')
        if logs:
            print(f"Console logs found in {url}:")
            for log_entry in logs:
                print(log_entry['level'], log_entry['message'])
            print()
        time.sleep(5)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error occurred while accessing {url}: {ex}")


test_urls = [''] # add urls to test

with ChromeDriver(username, password) as driver:
    for url in test_urls:
        check_console_logs(driver, url)
```

However, if I pause it in the debugger and open the devtools in the browser which was spawned by Python, I am able to see all the logs. I tried quite a lot but I still can not log any of the Javascript messages in Python.

I see only some other logs, which I am not interested in, because what I want to do is to call the different urls of my project in order to see if some unexpected warnings or errors are printed from my program flow.

The driver.capabilities shows browserVersion 122.06261.129 and chromedriverVersion is 122.0.6261.128 and I use selenium 4.18.1 and Python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out now after looking deeper into this link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2976

I needed to add also a service to the driver and set the *--verbose* argument

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
...
def __enter__(self):
    ...
    service = Service(service_args=["--verbose"])
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=service)
    ...
```